# Я хочу получить массив данных через API и вывести эти данные на страницу, но постоянно ошибки. Подскажите как решить? REACT

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CurrentInput from "./components/currentInput"

class App extends Component {
    mas = [];
    backFunc = async () => {
        let api_url = await fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`);
        let data = await api_url.json();
        this.mas = data;
    };

    render() {
        this.backFunc();
        console.log(this.mas);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <CurrentInput data={this.mas}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;





import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CurrentInput extends Component {
    render() {
        const listItem = this.props.data.map(item => (
                <div>
                    <p>{item}</p>
                </div>
            )
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Click</button>
                { listItem }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CurrentInput;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения информации (запросов к api) следует использовать метод жизненного цикла компонента `componentDidMount`, а данные хранить в `state`.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CurrentInput from "./components/currentInput"

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      data: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
       this.backFunc();
    }

    backFunc = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`);
        const data = await res.json();
        this.setState({ data });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <CurrentInput data={this.state.data}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Всё равно ошибка. Теперь data null

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

App.render

src/App.js:22
  19 | 
  20 | render() {
  21 |     return (
  22 |         <div className="App">
  23 |             {console.log(this.state.data)}
  24 |         </div>
  25 |     );

Comment: @АлександрРадченко я сделал опечатку сразу, сейчас поправил! Попробуйте еще раз!

Comment: Да, я пересмотрел всё, понял и исправил, спасибо большое!))